# Problema de actualización con Tomcat6 y MySQL

Tags: mysql, tomcat, cache

Tengo funcionando una aplicación web montada con Java, MySQL y Tomcat6.
Por otro lado hay un script que debe insertar registros nuevos en la base de datos (imita un caso de uso concreto de la aplicación web).

Cuando el script hace su trabajo la aplicación web parece ignorar los cambios al realizar consultas a una vista del MySQL. La vista del MySQL se actualiza correctamente.

¿Es posible que Tomcat esté cacheando la vista y sólo se actualice al realizar modificaciones a través de la aplicación web?
¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias!

Comment: Revisa que no se trate de que te falte un commit para que los cambios se hagan efectivos en la base de datos.

Comment: No utilizo commits (todos los cambios son definitivos). Tras los cambios que realiza el script la base de datos se queda tal y como debería.